# How to set the number of lines per page while converting text to pdf?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm converting text to pdf . Iam able to add header and footer to the pdf. But unable to give the number of lines per page. ie. if give 5 , after 5 lines, new page has to start.
Please help me.

Comment: The moment people see my name in your code (e.g. `com.lowagie`), they know that you are using a version of iText that dates at least from July 2009. That's a very long time ago. Versions that old have technical as well as legal issues. You should upgrade as soon as possible as there have been a lot of fixes in the last 6 years.

Comment: Deleting all your code made your problem unfathomable.